# How to use prepared statements in Sequel for MySQL2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prepared-statement, sequel, mysql2

Are we able to enable prepared statements in Sequel for the MySQL2 database adapter?

The documentation says that we can create prepared statements but the driver does not support bound variables.

Can someone elaborate on this and how are we supposed to use prepared statements?

Answer (score 1):

Sequel supports bound variables in prepared statements in the MySQL and MySQL2 adapters.  It doesn't support bound variables in non-prepared statements on the adapters, though.